# Setting file handle attribute in a Class::Std class in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a Perl class *LogManager* that is to be used to write logs to a file. For that I have written a **Class::Std class** with following specifications

```
package LogManager;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Class::Std;
use FileHandle;

my %fName     : ATTR( :name<fName> :default<"log">);
my %fLocation : ATTR( :name<fLocation> :default<"./">);
my %fHandle   : ATTR( :name<fHandle> :default<undef>);

sub START {
    my ($self, $ident, $args_ref) = @_;   
    my $logfile = $self->get_fLocation(). '/' . $self->get_fName();
    $self->set_fHandle(FileHandle->new("> $logfile"));
}

sub log {
    my ($self, $msg) = @_;
    print $self->get_fHandle(), $msg;
}

1;
```

What I know of Class::Std is that one can use get and set functions (eg. get_fName(), set_fName()) to read and write values of the attributes.
So, I have defined a [START() function](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Std#START()) as above.

I have used this object as follows

```
my $fh = LogManager->new();
LogManager::log($fh, "This is my log");
```

However, instead of writing to the file, following is being printed on the terminal

```
FileHandle=GLOB(0x5dcdd0)This is my log
```

I could think of a reason for this. In the START() function third line - there is something else happening than what I intend of - (might be it is copying address of the file handle object - this is a guess).

I'm new to Perl, and can't think of a different way to set the file handle. What I could think of now is creating a normal class instead of a **Class::Std** class and write something like

```
my $fHandle = FileHandle->new("> $logfile");
```

But, what I wanted to know - is there a way I can achieve the same using **Class::Std**, by some modifications to the above code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `print` to a file handle is different: there's no comma. Also, for complex structures, you need  curly braces:

```
print { $self->get_fHandle } $msg;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried different ways - even without commas, but it was giving error that way. What I didn't know was we have to enclose the first argument in curly braces.

Comment: One could also use `$self->get_fHandle->print($msg);`.